# How to add values to an bson.D object

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I'm working with golang and the MongoDB driver, I want to patch one of my objects according to the data I get from the outside:

I have a struct:

```
type Pivot struct {
    Email        string             `json:"email"`
    Base         string             `json:"base"`
}
```

And the patch (with MongoDB Update)

```
setMap := bson.D{
        {"$set", setElements},
    }

res, err := collection.UpdateMany(
    ctx,
    filter,
    setMap,
)
```

And I want to make the setObject a little bit dynamic:

```
if len(pivot.Base) > 0 {
  setElements.append("base", pivot.Base) //this doesn't work...
}
if len(pivot.Email) > 0 {
  setElements.append("email", pivot.Email)
}
```

I' ve seen that the setObject [can be built like](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/examples/documentation_examples/examples.go#L1517)

```
{"$set", bson.D{
    {"processed", pivot.Processed},
}
```

But how can I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Append a [DocElem](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#DocElem) (mgo) or an [E](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#E) (go.mongodb.org) to the slice depending on the client you are using.

```
var setElements bson.D
if len(pivot.Base) > 0 {
  setElements = append(setElements, bson.E{"base", pivot.Base})
}
if len(pivot.Email) > 0 {
    setElements = append(setElements, bson.E{"email", pivot.Email})
}

setMap := bson.D{
    {"$set", setElements},
}
```

Replace bson.E with bson.DocElem for mgo.

Comment: It took me a while to check that bson.D is an abson.E array, I had declared as ```setElements := []bson.E{}```

Comment: Is this the last resort? I have lots of fields in my database so any better approach?